Can someone who is not you find out your date of birth from your confirmation code on your airline ticket?
I had to give my date of birth in order to book my flight, for a job, yet I do not want the company to know my age. Can someone who is not you find out your birthdate from entering in or telling the airline your confirmation code?

It might depend on the airline.

This will very much depend on which legislations apply, i.e. what countries are involved.

It may be more about "legal". If they ask your age and you do not answer, they may deny your application (Note: in many countries it is illegal), but in general nobody can check your personal details without your consent (facebook e co have your consent). -- Often with booking reference and surname, one can see all details (and often they can also ask refund themselves, so never share such code but to trusted people).

The confirmation code itself does not encode your date of birth, but it is possible that your airline's website shows the details of all passengers in the booking, including dates of birth. That is something you can easily check for yourself - just look for a "manage your booking" or "check-in online" or similar link on their website, enter your booking code and surname, and see what information you can find.
If the website does not show it then it is unlikely that the airline would reveal it over the phone, though not impossible. If the company did call the airline to ask this information that would seem like "social engineering" to me - probably not something any ethical company would do.

I wonder if a company that employs someone without knowing their age is an ethical company.

@Willeke Indeed. In many countries age discrimination by employers is illegal, age should not be taken into account in employment decisions. Not sure what the OP’s reason is for not wanting to disclose their correct DoB to the company since it’s likely needed by the employer for a variety of reasons including, for example, workforce monitoring, and pension records.

@Traveller in many (most?) jurisdictions, once a person has actually been hired, the employer (at least people in HR and payroll) will most definitely know the employee's age/date of birth, as that is part of records they need, directly or indirectly. Before a hiring decision is taken, it's probably a bit more variable, but I would definitely not count on it (they will probably ask for the info before being able to issue a contract).

Maybe, maybe not. All of this seems off-topic for the asker's travel-related question.

@EM0 Not necessarily. The broader aspects of why an employer usually needs the correct DoB might not be obvious to eg someone travelling for a job from a country where age discrimination law is not as robust as the destination country.

@Willeke I once hired someone for my team and worked with her for a few years and never knew her age. I figured it was none of my business, she was old enough that there was no question of her not being an adult and, as long as she does her job well, why should I care how old she is? So I never asked and she never volunteered the information. If anything, I would be more worried about a company insisting on knowing someone's age being unethical than the other way around.

@terdon: If a company does any sort of background checks, they may want to know whether the "Adam B. Clarkson" is  the "Adam B. Clarkson, born January 2, 2003" who according to public court records has been convicted multiple times of shoplifting, or is some other "Adam B. Clarkson" born on any other date.

@supercat oh sure, and in most cases the company will indeed ask for this information and that is also perfectly fine. I was just surprised that Willeke suggested it might be unethical not to ask which seems odd to me, hence my personal anecdote.

@terdon: Many jurisdictions impose minimum-age requirements for some kinds of jobs.  Willeke was probably alluding to people who hire young workers without regard for whether they satisfy those requirements.

@terdon, I live in a country where everybody have to show their official ID and the company has to store a copy. But I would find it suspicious as someone hides their age as I would assume that they are too young for the work they do, and an employer who allows it is likely to know they are too young.

Just a guess, but OP may be more concerned about age playing a role in the hiring process without them being even aware of it, than about sharing it after getting the job.

@supercat The employer doesn't need to know that; that can be handled directly between the employee and the background check company. This is especially how it works for highly invasive checks like security clearances.
